# ASP.Net- Items inside the Content Placeholder is not showing in .aspx pages

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have an error in a content placeholder. When I try to create a master page it shows me an error as below in the master page and I can't see any items such as buttons, labels, etc. inside the .aspx pages.

Also I can't add content placeholder from the VS Toolbox, it shows a cross mark on the Content placeholder button.

```
{ Error Rendering Control - ContentPlaceHolder1

An unhandled exception has occurred.

This control can only be used in a MaserPage.}
```

Comment: We could use your ASPX code to help debug it. Also, is it ASP Classic or ASP.NET? ASPX files are for ASP.NET, but you tagged it as ASP Classic.

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET master](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) pages allow you to create a consistent layout for the pages in your application. A single master page defines the look and feel and standard behavior that you want for all of the pages (or a group of pages) in your application. 
In addition to static text and controls that will appear on all pages, the master page also includes one or more ContentPlaceHolder controls. These placeholder controls define regions where replaceable content will appear. In turn, the replaceable content is defined in content pages. Here is an example of a master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 
1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server" >
    <title>Master page title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>
       <tr>
           <td><asp:contentplaceholder id="Main" runat="server" /></td>
           <td><asp:contentplaceholder id="Footer" runat="server" /></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here should be a content page looking like

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    Main content.
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" Runat="Server" >
    Footer content.
</asp:content>
```

please read more here about [ASP.NET Master Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)